# How to compile a msvc static library to be linked from DMD?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, d, dmd

I've been spending a lot of time trying to build D bindings for an open source C library.

I'm using msvc to build the C a static .lib, but DMD is unable to recognize the .lib file, it seems to be a problem related to the COFF/OMF incompatibilities.

What is the easiest way to compile a C library, OMF compatible, to be linked from D?

Answer (score 1):

Port the header file into a `.di` file with matching function signatures and `extern (C)`. Then use that as the `import` target. You can use the [htod tool](http://dlang.org/htod.html) to help with that.

See http://dlang.org/spec/interfaceToC.html

Comment: the problem is not importing the C signatures, but rather linking to a msvc .lib file

Comment: http://dlang.org/changelog/2.069.0.html#link-against-vs2015
What version are you using?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'm using VS2012, would this work too?

Comment: I don't mind upgrading to VS2015 as this is a new project. I'll need to upgrade to the latest version of DMD as well. Thanks!